# Zero lead digit for a number removed when concatenating in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a couple of PL SQL Functions to return a currency and amount from a compressed field. These work perfectly individually.

e.g.

```
Select currency(DATA)
from dual;
```

returns GBP

```
Select amount(DATA)
from dual;
```

returns 0.1

Concatenating the 2...

```
Select currency(DATA) || amount(DATA)
from dual;
```

returns GBP.1

I want it to be GBP0.1, any idea what is going wrong?

The amount function returns a NUMBER the currency a VARCHAR2. It is Oracle SQL.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: because when you concat || the two things together, oracle is being asked implicitly to convert the number to a string, and the leading zero isn't really important so you lose it. If you want to keep it, have your function return the amount as a string, e.g. '0.1' vs 0.1

Comment: Please, provide any code of what those functions are doing. No one can know what is wrong when there's no even a signature of the function and implicit conversions may do whatever they want

Comment: Changing the function to return either CHAR/VARCHAR2/STRING returns .1 when using the amount function on it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to pursue this the way you're trying, you can format the number using `TO_CHAR(your_number, '90.99')`.

Example:

```
SELECT 'GBP' || TO_CHAR(0.1, '90.99') FROM DUAL;
```

More formatting examples are detailed here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABFJEAA

Note that there is a way to extract the local currency, and that may be a better way to get `GBP` than whatever method you're currently using (which you don't provide in your sample).

Comment: Excellent that has worked thanks.

Comment: Cool.  If that's acceptable as an answer, please mark it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: In case of more digits it should have enough `9`s to carry out all the digits